# How can I create a store procedured that allows me to update a customer based on unknown parameters?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is showing me an error on this line (PREPARE stmt from mySql;) I've tried a few changes in the code but I don't know what is causing the error, I'd really appreciate any help,thanks in advance.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateStaff 
(
    id tinyint, 
    f_name VARCHAR(45), 
    l_name VARCHAR(45), 
    address tinyint, 
    pic blob, 
    emai VARCHAR(50),
    store tinyint, 
    isActive tinyint, 
    userN VARCHAR(16), 
    pass VARCHAR(50)
 )

BEGIN

DECLARE mySql VARCHAR(100);
SET mySql = 'UPDATE staff SET ';

IF f_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql= CONCAT(mySql, 'first_name = f_name, ');
END IF;

IF l_name IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'last_name = l_name, '); 
END IF;

IF address IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'address_id = address, ');
END IF;

IF pic IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'picture = pic, ');
END IF;

IF emai IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'email = emai, ');
END IF;

IF store IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'store_id = store, ');
END IF;

IF isActive IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql= CONCAT(mySql, 'active = isActive, ');
END IF;

IF userN IS NOT NULL THEN 
    SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, 'username = userN, ');
END IF;

IF pass IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET mySql= CONCAT(mySql, 'password = pass ');
END IF;

SET mySql = CONCAT(mySql, ' WHERE staff_id = id');
    
**PREPARE stmt from mySql;**
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I chekced if each statement has its corresponding semicolon, but nothing worked

Comment: What about trailing commas? If only one thing gets updated, it will look something like `UPDATE staff SET first_name = f_name, WHERE staff_id = id` so that comma after `f_name` will cause problems (and any other columns as well, f_name is just an example).

Comment: Temporarily change you SP to return the value of mySql and it should be easy to see where the issue is

Comment: the passed information is not processed by your code, so isactivated for example in the string will stay isactivated as text in the query and will so not be recognized by the server

Comment: even fixing it it, will still be vulnerable to sql injection., only way to fix it would be creatingb a massive flow conrol to get all possible combination of columns and process them. so that we are clear all possible combination around  362880

Comment: @nbk There's no SQL injection. They're not putting the values of the parameters into the SQL, they're referencing them  as variables.

Comment: @Barmar if he uses prepared statements like in the question yes it would

Comment: @nbk No it won't. `SET password = pass` doesn't substitute the value of `pass`. It would be injection if he did `CONCAT(mySql, 'password = "', pass, '",')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `SET` list will end with `,` unless `pass` is being updated.

Instead of dynamic SQL, you can use `IFNULL()` to test whether the parameter is set. If the parameter is `NULL`, you assign the column's value back to itself to keep it the same.

```
UPDATE staff SET
    first_name = IFNULL(f_name, first_name),
    last_name = IFNULL(l_name, last_name),
    ...
    password = IFNULL(pass, password)
WHERE staff_id = id;
```